# Flatlist - lista subindo e invadindo espaço do menu

Tags: react, expo

Boa noite, estou com um problema em minha aplicação em react, minha lista (flatlist) quando fica com muitos itens, a lista acaba subindo na página e invadindo o espaço do menu de minha aplicação que esta inserido acima dela.

index.js (Home)

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import Header from '../../components/Header';
import Actions from '../../components/Actions';
import List from '../../components/list';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header name="Olá, usuário." />
        
        <Actions/>

        <Text style={styles.title}>Mapas:</Text>
        
        <List/>

    </View>
    
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#fafafa',
  },
    title:{
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    margin: 14,
    marginEnd: 14,
  }
});
```

Conteúdo das configurações de index.js (List)

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      backgroundColor: '#fafafa',
    },
    list:{
      marginStart: 14,
      marginEnd: 14,
    }
```

[Segue imagem do problema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2oQA.jpg)

Estou me embaralhando nesse ajuste, no mais esta tudo correto, alguém pode me explicar onde estou pecando?
Obrigado!

Comment: Ainda procuro uma solução, quando achar posto aqui.

Answer (score -2):

Consegui resolver, estava esquecendo que tinha definido uma animação nos ícones dos botões que acabei mudando de ideia, porém não tinha removido a seguinte linha:

```
   marginTop: 10,
    }
```

Ele estava empurrando minha lista pra cima do menu, após remover o marginTop consegui resolver o problema, fica a dica pra quem ter o mesmo descuido que tive.